# Reading from IP Camera (RTSP) using FFmpeg results in 5xx Server Error

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

I have a scenario where I am trying to read from IP camera using RTSP method.

On my development PC everything is working fine, the rtsp url is something like:

```
rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.60:554
```

but when I try to test it over a friend's place, he has different camera (Axis IP camera), and the url fails to open.
The self generated log is something like:

```
Error: avformat_open_input()
error message: Server returned 5XX Server Error reply
```

I tried opening it using HTTP tunneling, but this time I'm getting a different error:

```
error message: Error number -5 occurred
```

The latter error message even appears on my dev PC (just to mention that I tried this as well); so HTTP tunnel is no good.

Any one knows how to fix 5XX Server Error?

Thanks,

Comment: in the other environment (at your friend place) is the camera really streaming to 192.168.1.60:554? are the credentials the same? can you make sure it is the case by capturing using wireshark?

Comment: You need to make sure that the camera is exposing the same RTSP URL. The URL is dependent on camera make and model.

Comment: @ UmNyobe, no, but looking at the log files he gave me back, it is actually similar to this: rtsp://user:pass@192.168.10.4:554... I need to the there physically to examine using wireshark...

Comment: @  CadentOrange , he says supported protocols according to specs are: IPv4/v6, HTTP, HTTPSa , SSL/TLSa , QoS Layer 3 DiffServ, FTP, CIFS/SMB, SMTP, Bonjour, UPnPTM, SNMP v1/v2c/v3 (MIB-II), DNS, DynDNS, NTP, RTSP, RTP, SFTP, TCP, UDP, IGMP, RTCP, ICMP, DHCP, ARP, SOCKS, SSH, NTCIP NTCIP; which includes RTSP as well....

Comment: Friend is using this particular model: AXIS Q6045-S, reading specs somewhere gives me hint RTSP url for this particular model should be like: rtsp://ip_address/mpeg4/media.amp ; maybe I need to change my implementation in this format: rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.60:554 to rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.60:554/mpeg4/media.amp. Maybe this (with change) will work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I ended up knowing his camera is not Axis Q6045-S, it is P3346-VE version.

Whole issue was because of incorrect URL. Correct URL to read from RTSP (for this particular model) is as follows:

```
rtsp://uname:pass@192.168.1.3:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264
```

Then everything works fine.